# Elasticsearch wild card query ignoring some words

Tags: elasticsearch

The word "beurre" seems to be ignored by wildcard queries "beurr*".
For example, I have a data with name "beurre de cacahuète".

Normal query finds this data:

```
{
   "query": {      
     "query_string" : {                 
       "query" : "beurre",
     }
   }                     
}
```

And so does a wildcard query on another word:

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "name" : "cacahuet*"  
        }
    }
}
```

But a this wildcard query finds no match:

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "name" : "beur*"  
        }
    }
}
```

I have a lot of data that should match, and find absolutely no reason for this behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by using the "light_french" stemmer.
Removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query_string to wildcard

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "{TEXT_OR_KEYWORD_FIELD}" : "*{STRING_PATTERN}*"
        }
    }
}
```

SRC: https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-regexp-and-wildcard-queries-to-return-documents-with-a-partial-string-match

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same result with this: it works for other words, but not for "beurr". I'll edit the question